# Image's stretch exceeds the maximum allowable space as a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a problem with an image stretching in a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeviceModelListBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
        BorderThickness="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceModels}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Rows="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="DeviceModelGrid"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="pack://application:,,,/AppAssembly;component/Resource/Filename.png" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My images are bigger than ListBox available space and I just want to stretch images to stop at Grid's row height and column width, but every Image's stretch property value do nothing. How should I limit Image's size to available space in XAML? The same thing happens with a ViewBox.

Comment: If you change your current code above to use Strecth=Fill does it not work?

Comment: Nothing happens - still Image exceeds ListBox size and ScrollBars appears.

Comment: Set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the ListBox.

Comment: Try binding Width and Height of UniformGrid inside ItemsPanelTemplate to ListBox Height and Width. Something like below,

Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                 Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualHeight}"

Comment: After setting the above properties the images are fit to each Grid's column definition, but height are not adjusted to whole list item. May be you can able to figure out on your own after this fix.

Comment: Try and let us know if this is what you want.

Comment: It is typically never necessary to bind the Width and Height of UI elements in WPF. Just disable the ScrollBars (vertically, horizontally or both) and layout will do the rest.